# How can I return to Unity notifications after installing XFCE4?

Tags: unity, xfce, notification, desktop-environments

After I installed XFCE4, the XFCE notifications are being displayed instead of the Unity ones. Even in Unity sessions. How do I set it up so that I get Unity notifications in Unity sessions and XFCE4 notifications in XFCE sessions. If I can't do that, I just want to know how to get the Unity notifications back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure about the first part, but if you don't want to use the Xfce notifications (and thus, use Unity's notifications instead), you can remove the "xfce4-notifyd" package:

```
sudo apt-get remove xfce4-notifyd
```

Then log out and log back in.